# How to save object state/selection?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms. One is a main form(form1), and other one(form2) is called when I press a button.

When I press a button, form2 shows and it contains several checkboxes and comboboxes.

My question is, how can I store or save the checkbox state and combobox selection so that I can use them (check their state/selection) in my form1 after I close form2?

Here's a basic example:

```
Form2:

--I click on checkbox and the state changes:

checkbox1.Checked = true;

Form1:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (checkbox1.Checked == true)
{
MessageBox.Show("Checkbox on form2 is checked")
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use the same form instance for Form2 and they will be saved. Closing a form does not clear any of its control values.

Comment: And how do I do that? lol

Comment: See my answer for some code.

Answer (score 1):

Use Databinding and an object to pass around. The following example demonstrates how to achieve this without having to make anything static. Because the values become bound together if you do: state.IsChecked = false; that would also uncheck the checkbox on Form2.

Don't just add global variables, that's a large pain waiting to happen.

```
class Form1: Form
{
    private State state = new State();

    public Form1()
    {
        Load += HandleLoad;
    }

    public HandleLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", state, "IsChecked"); // or just query state.IsChecked
    }
    public void someEvent_Handler()
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Bind(state);
        form2.Show();
    }
}

class Form2: Form
{
    public void Bind(State state)
    {
        checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", state, "IsChecked");
    }
}

class State
{
    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you are creating new form instance every time, something like:

```
private void OpenForm2
{
    //open form2:
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog(this);

    //read form2 values:
    if (form2.Checkbox1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Checkbox on form2 is checked")
    }
}
```

Instead, use one global instance and just show it every time, this way preserving its state:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
private void OpenForm2
{
    //open form2:
    form2.ShowDialog(this);

    //read form2 values:
    if (form2.Checkbox1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Checkbox on form2 is checked")
    }
}
```